# How do I get an RSS feed of my YouTube subscriptions?

Tags: youtube, rss

The default "Subscriptions" feed on the YouTube homepage shows all of the activity of the people that I am subscribed to on YouTube or have in circles on Google+. However, I'm most interested in new videos that the people I subscribe to (either on YouTube or by circling on Google+) create and post (neglecting comments or sharing other people's videos - what you see when you check the "show uploads only" checkbox on the YouTube homepage). However, being able to bring anything off of the YouTube homepage and into Google Reader as an RSS feed would be good.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It seems that the proposed answer has stopped working. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @mcb still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for 2017 it can be solved with OPML file export/import. For more details visit the official YouTube support answer.

[https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6224202](https://web.archive.org/web/20200807224917/https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6224202)

Comment: This was working until at least October 24, 2020, but since November 1, 2020 it no longer seems to be working.

Answer (score 18):

You can get RSS feed by username, something like this:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/{username}/newsubscriptionvideos`

Example:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/google/newsubscriptionvideos`.

How to get Youtube username ([source](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/feed-for-youtube-subscriptions.html)):

1. Go to [youtube.com](http://youtube.com)
2. Click on the arrow next to your username at the top right of the
   screen.
3. Click Channel under My Account.
4. Enter the username you'd like by typing it into the text field
   provided.
5. Click Next.
6. Choose your privacy settings from the options provided.
7. Click All Done!

**Steps to get username if you've already linked your G+ account to your YouTube account**

1. Go to youtube.com
2. Click on the arrow next to your username at the top right of the
   screen.
3. Click My channel under YouTube
4. Take the ID from the address bar `http://www.youtube.com/channel/{id}`

Comment: How might I get my user name? My profile goes to my Google+ profile, so does that make my user name that sequence of numbers, because when I tried that, I get a page with the error message "Exception message unavailable".

Comment: You have asked about Youtube or Google+. I've answered about Youtube.

Comment: I'm asking how I get my RSS feed by username. I don't know what my user name is so I can get my subscriptions.

Comment: Username is Youtube username. So, in you case is `ThomasO610`. For Google+ use GPlusRSS.

Comment: Oh. That's not intuitive at all. I thought my YouTube user name went away when I merged it with my Google+ account, so I was trying with the URL numbers to my G+ profile page. This appears to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I haven't answered correctly, so we have some problems... I'm very pleased you find what are you looking for.

Comment: If you could just add a description of how to get your YouTube user name (especially for someone who has merged with G+, where their Profile link brings them to their G+ profile page), that would be perfect. Other than that, this perfectly addresses my question.

Comment: As of today (11/25/2013), when I try to use the method outlined in this answer, I get the message "Login required to view this user's new subscription videos.", even though I've confirmed that I'm logged in to Youtube.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out I had to go into the "Privacy" section of my account and uncheck "keep subscriptions private".

Comment: It seems that this has stopped working.

Answer (score 4):

The working URL format would be:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_NAME/uploads
```

I just tested this, and it should work on any news reader. Just replace "YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_NAME" with your channel's name, or the channel you want to subscribe to. No need to be logged in to YouTube at all.

Also, here is a YouTube clip I did on the topic:

[How To Find The RSS Feed To A YouTube Channel](http://youtu.be/vL564qe2RDI)

Comment: But that is just a feed for a single channel. The question was for all the subscribed channels.

Answer (score 1):

While Vukašin's answer is great and has helped me for quite a while now, it stopped working 3 days ago. The reason is that Google slightly changed their API and now requires authentication via OAuth tokens. There is even a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6333) on it.

I did not find an easy way to fix this, but the [comments section](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6333#c20) of the bug report linked to a short PHP script that one can use as a temporary fix.

You will have to have some server to run this (and the Google API) on and register the project on the website, just like explained in the comment. I also want to mention in general that this keeps the RSS feed working for the Google API V2 for now, but a V3 is on the way and will probably break most of this, since it will be using JSON returns and not the easy to parse XML feed of V2. So this is merely a temporary fix for people who have their own server running anyways.

I hope this helps other people who were wondering why the stream broke all of a sudden. I also apologize for the probably slightly incorrect usage of some terms. I am by no means a web developer and just very glad that I found this solution offered by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-append `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=` to the channel unique identifier.

For example, lets assume that the channel url is `https://www.youtube.com/channel/feed/UCpjNXONNE-JUz74ACsRCgcw`. So the rss feed URL would be `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCpjNXONNE-JUz74ACsRCgcw`.

Answer (score -3):

If you have Android, there is an app for this here the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youtuberss.reader

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: got it, d app works great for me so i tot it nice 2 share it u all